# How to transform this data into assignations using awk or other?

Tags: awk

I need to transform some data into assignments. I'm pretty sure it looks like a pretty straightforward job for awk, but I am far from confortable with it.

Each data element (and columns) are tab-separated.
Data elements may contain spaces and special characters, but no TABs.

example input :

```
column1 column2 column3
rowA1   rowA2   rowA3
rowB1   rowB2   rowB3
```

expected output :

```
column1 = rowA1
column2 = rowA2
column3 = rowA3

column1 = rowB1
column2 = rowB2
column3 = rowB3
```

(with arbitrary number of rows, not exceeding hundreds)

Any clue how to do this ? (with awk or any standard command-line tool on a linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
{
    if (NR==1){
        for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i){
            arr[i] = $i
        }
    }else{
        for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i){
            print(arr[i]," = ",$i)
        }
    }
    print("")
}
```

To run:

```
awk -f script.awk input
```

Comment: I needed to insert this first line into your script:  `BEGIN { FS = "[\t]+" } ;` , otherwise the fields containing spaces were shifted to wrong columns. It works nicely now. Thank you for helping me with my first awk task!

Comment: @Pac0 Right, I forgot you mentioned your file is separated by tabs.

Comment: good script.  i'd upvote if you took the time to explain how it works and turn it into a detailed answer.  teaching is better than cargo-culting.  Pac0 seems to understand it but anyone else who stumbles across this may not.  Also, you seem to have a habit of writing awk script fragments and then saying "run with `awk -f script.awk input`" - that works, but why not just make it a `#!/usr/bin/awk` script?

Answer (score 3):

```
cat data |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a a; do
   case ${flag+'set'} in
      "set" )
         set -- "${a[@]}"
         for c in "${C[@]}"; do echo "$c = $1"; shift; done
         echo ;;

      * ) C=( "${a[@]}" ); flag= ;;
   esac
done

sed -Ee '
   1h;1N
   /^\n$/{
      $d;P;g;N
   }
   s/^(\S+)\s*((\S.*)?)\n(\S+)\s*((\S.*)?)/\1 = \4\n\2\n\5/
   P;D
' data

perl -F'\t+' -lane '
   @C or @C = @F,next;
   print "$C[$_] = $F[$_]" for 0 .. $#C;
   eof or print q[];
' data
```

---

## Result

```
column1 = rowA1
column2 = rowA2
column3 = rowA3

column1 = rowB1
column2 = rowB2
column3 = rowB3
```

---

## Explanation

1. `bash`

   *) Store the first line in an array `C` during the time the flag is unset. Then promptly set it so that next time onwards we don't arrive here.
   *) The array `a` is split up into arguments using the `set` command.
   *) Then we cycle through the columns, accessed via, "${c[@]}" in a `for` loop and printed alongwith $1 ( which is then shifted out)
   *) Note IFS is set to tab via the `$'\t'` construct. Since it is one of special characters hence a run of these would be collapsed into one and so we won't be seeing empty fields.
2. `perl`

   *) Set the FS to one or more TABs: `-F'\t+'` and turn on autosplit mode.
   *) Same logic as with `bash` based solution, wherein we store the columns data found in 1st line in the `@C` array. The arrays `@C` and current record fields data in `@F` are printed taking one from each.
3. `sed`

   *) Here we first convert all TABs to spaces.
   *) Store the first line columns data in the hold space.
   *) For all the other lines, append the columns to the current row.
   *) Then we keep picking first elements from current row/column and shrinking the pattern space by taking away these printed stuff.
   *) Stop condition happens when no spaces are left.

Comment: I prefer pfnuesel's simple `awk` answer, but I appreciate the try anyway. and +1 for detailed explanations. (Well, i would have  given +1 but I haven't enough reputation to upvote yet, sorry!)